# Dynamic Tailwind CSS columns not working properly (Math.min)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm developing a recipe web using React with TS and Tailwind CSS.
There's a page called "my recipes" where an user's recipes are displayed. I decided to use grid in order to create an equal number of columns based on the length of the recipes array and the screen width.

```
return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
            {!loading && (
                <>
                    {recipes.length === 0 ? (
                        <div>
                            <h1 className="text-4xl">You have no recipes yet</h1>
                            <Link to="/add-recipes" className="mt-6">
                                Add a recipe
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    ) : (
                        <>
                            <h1 className="title">Your recipes</h1>
                            <div
                                className={`grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-${Math.min(2, recipes.length)} md:grid-cols-${Math.min(3, recipes.length)} gap-4 mt-6 p-4`}
                            >
                                {recipes.map((recipe, index) => (
                                    <RecipeCard recipe={recipe} key={index}/>
                                ))}
                            </div>
                        </>
                    )}
                </>
            )}
        </div>
    );
```

So, as I explained above, the div where the recipes are rendered has a className that sets the amount of columns dynamically.
At first this worked, but sometimes when I restart the app I only see one column regardless of the screen width. I've tried to find the problem and it seems like Math.min is probably having issues, but I'm not quite sure yet.

I tried not using Math.min and it appears to work, but I'd like to fix it.

Comment: how many recipe cards you see when you see only 1 column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot dynamically concatenate partial class names with Tailwind as it requires the full class to be present to generate the necessary CSS.

You could use CSS variables to work around this:

```js
const gridColTemplate = n => `repeat(${n}, minmax(0, 1fr))`;
```

```
<div className='grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-[--sm-cols] md:grid-cols-[--md-cols] gap-4 mt-6 p-4'
    style={{'--sm-cols': gridColTemplate(Math.min(2, recipes.length)), '--md-cols': gridColTemplate(Math.min(3, recipes.length))}}
>
```